# sql table data to html table using jquery with 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

i tried but error : to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) I don't know fix it.
View with HTML and Jquery
HTML

```
<table id="Form1" class="table table-striped display nowrap" cellspacing="10px">
                                    
                                        <thead>
                                       
                                          <tr>
                                            <th col-name="VesselName">Tên tàu</th>
                                            <th col-name="VesselID">Mã tàu</th>
                                            <th col-name="OutboundVoyage">Chuyến</th>
                                          </tr>
                                       </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                
                                          
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
```

Ajax Jquery
I don't think the url is wrong

```
     ////// Form1
          
    
            $.ajax({

url: '/Tally/Tally.js/get1',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
var html = '';
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
html += '\<tr\>';
html += '\<th\>' + item.VesselName + '\</th\>';
html += '\<th\>' + item.VesselID + '\</th\>';
html += '\<th\>' + item.OutboundVoyage + '\</th\>';
html += '\</tr\>';
});
$('#Form1 tbody').append(html);
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
});\`\`\`
```

Controller Backend JS

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var auth = require('../../middlewares/authentication');
const TallyModel = require('../../models/tally_model.js');
router.get('/', auth, async function (req, res, next) {
  //let dataList=await VesselModel.loadTrfCode(req);
    res.loadContent('tally/tally1', {});

});

router.post('/get1', auth, function (req, res, next) {
  TallyModel.loadVessel(req).then((data)=>{
      res.status(200).json({data});
  }).catch((error)=>{
      res.status(200).json({error});
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

I have checked all the errors but for some reason, the data cannot be returned.
Model: KnexJS

```
"use strict"
const { gtos, gtosglobal, knex_once } = require('../config/database');
const moment = require('moment-timezone');


module.exports.loadVessel = async (req) => {
  return await req.gtos('[DT_VESSEL]')
    .select('VesselName', 'VesselID', 'OutboundVoyage')
    .orderBy('VesselID')
    .catch(err => console.log(err)) || [];
}
```

Comment: *I don't think the url is wrong* - it's giving a 404, the url is wrong.

Comment: Thank you! My path : 
\views\tally\tally1.ejs
\models\tally_model.js
\controllers\Tally\Tally.js
Can you help me check it.